# How to query an inverted index with non-fixed amount of keyword(s)?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

How to query inverted index list / collection if the keywords are dynamic (user can input as many as he / she wants)?

I am quite confused in building the "WHERE" clause, since the number of keywords is not a fixed amount.

Just in case if someone doesn't familiar with inverted index : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index

This is the class model of an index :

```
public class Index
{
    public string word;
    public List<int> referenceIDs;

    //constructor
}
```

And this is the collection :

```
List<Index> invertedIndices = new List<Index>();
```

Thank you.

P.S. I prefer an answer in lambda expression, if possible, although any sql based language should be fine too.

EDITED :

1. I edit fields from private to public to make it more understandable.
2. You need to read the wiki (it's really simple since the example is really understandable) if you don't familiar to inverted index.

Comment: On what will you query, given that the only fields in Index are private. Can you try writing a sample query in plain language, so that we can better understand the question?

Comment: `//properties` should be the public getter setter, but I've edited the fields into public instead, so it's more understandable to non-C# dev. Btw query is what I asked, so I don't know how to write a sample query to clarify my question. Thanks.

Comment: care to explain on the downvote?

Comment: Downvote was not me. I am a C# dev. Yes, you asked for the code for a query, but for me at least, the goal could be more clear. In plain language, perhaps you want a query, for example, that represents "return all referenceIds for a given word"?

Comment: In the morning, it all looks more clear: I think the problem is "return all referenceIds for a given *set* of words".

Comment: I'm not referring to you only by the downvote. no extreme prejudice. haha. And yes, that's the problem I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        var final = invertedIndices.Where(x => words.Contains(x.word))
                                   .SelectMany(y => y.referenceIDs)
                                   .GroupBy(z => z)
                                   .Where(a => a.Count() == words.Count())
                                   .Select(b => b.Key);
```

The unit test below demonstrates that this query retrieves only the expected results. I could have used a JOIN if I had converted the "words" list into a dictionary or some custom reference type. As it is, you can't join a list of strings with a list of reference types.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void InvertedIndiciesSearchReturnsMatchOnAllKeywords()
    {
        var words = new List<string>() { "Cow", "Horse" };
        var invertedIndices = new List<Index>()
        {
            new Index { word = "Pig", referenceIDs = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 8 }},
            new Index { word = "Chicken", referenceIDs = new List<int>() { 4, 8 }},
            new Index { word = "Horse", referenceIDs = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 8 }},
            new Index { word = "Goat", referenceIDs = new List<int>() { 3 }},
            new Index { word = "Cow", referenceIDs = new List<int>() { 1, 3 }},
            new Index { word = "Coward", referenceIDs = new List<int>() { 999 }}
        };

        // Contains is searching for x.word _in the list_ "words", not searching
        // to see if any of the _strings within words_ contains x.word.

        var final = invertedIndices.Where(x => words.Contains(x.word))
                                   .SelectMany(y => y.referenceIDs)
            // now limit the results by getting only those reference IDs
            // that appeared for every item in the input list
                                   .GroupBy(z => z)
                                   .Where(a => a.Count() == words.Count())
                                   .Select(b => b.Key);


        Assert.AreEqual(1, final.Count(), "result count");
        Assert.AreEqual(1, final.First(), "value '1' is shared by Cow and Horse and should be the only result");
    }
```

Comment: Is assert is the same as `Debug.Assert()`? And why it's needed at the last section of the query? And second, if I use contains, isn't COW will also read with keyword COWARD?

Comment: Edited for a better explanation. Assert.AreEqual is similar to Debug.Assert, but used in a unit test framework (e.g. MsTest or NUnit).

Comment: I still doesn't get what is assert used for. the program will also works fine if Assert doesn't used right? I've read msdn definition too. And what about COWARD will also queried if the keyword has COW?

Comment: btw, assuming there are 2 keywords, then distinct will return 1,2,2,3 as 1,2,3 instead of 2, right? but I think inverted index should return 2, since the returned IDs should have appearances in every keyword inputed. So, it should be "RETURN EVERY REFERENCE IDS WHICH APPEARS X TIMES, WHERE X IS THE NUMBER OF KEYWORDS"

Comment: I did assume that you would not want duplicated data. To get 1,2,2,3 back from the query, just remove the Distinct().

Comment: I don't want duplicated data, but, it should return `2` instead of `1,2,3` So, maybe that means, return IDs which got duplicated equal to the number of the keyword.

Comment: Try this. If it isn't right yet, then maybe follow Stackoverflow's suggestion to move the conversation to a chat? I haven't used that before.

Comment: Ah! The "limit" is the key I needed! Btw, I have 2 further questions. One, what is statement `Select(b=>b.Key)` for? This is the first time I use / will use `Key`. Two, your answer seems can't get if there's 2 `Index` that match the requirements, since it doesn't have `ToList()` or similar and is stored in a non-list field.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54810/discussion-between-moses-aprico-and-sfuqua).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to design your own collection.  A `Dictionary<string, List<int>>` would serve well as the underlying collection.  This makes your lookups quite fast.  Here's a partial implementation of such a class that shows how one such lookup would look like:

```
public class InvertedIndexCollection : IDictionary<string, List<int>>
{
    public class IndexedWord
    {
        public string Key
        {
            get
            {
                return kvp.Key;
            }
        }
        public List<int> Value
        {
            get
            {
                return kvp.Value;
            }
        }
        private KeyValuePair<string, List<int>> kvp = new KeyValuePair<string, List<int>>();

        public IndexedWord()
        {

        }
        public IndexedWord(string _key, List<int> _newvalue)
        {
            kvp = new KeyValuePair<string, List<int>>(_key, _newvalue.OrderBy(x => x).ToList());
        }
    }
    private Dictionary<string, List<int>> Collection = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return Collection.Count;
        }
    }
    public InvertedIndexCollection()
    {

    }
    public InvertedIndexCollection(Dictionary<string, List<int>> NewCollection)
    {
        Collection = NewCollection;
    }
    public List<int> this[string key]
    {
        get
        {
            return Collection[key];
        }
        set
        {
            Collection[key] = value;
        }
    }
    public void Add(IndexedWord NewItem)
    {
        if(Collection.ContainsKey(NewItem.Key))
            Collection[NewItem.Key].AddRange(NewItem.Value.Where(x => !Collection[NewItem.Key].Contains(x)));
        else
            Collection.Add(NewItem.Key, NewItem.Value);
    }
    public void Add(string Newkey, int Index)
    {
        if(Collection.ContainsKey(Newkey))
        {
            Collection[Newkey].Add(Index);
            Collection[Newkey].Sort();
        }
        else
            Collection.Add(Newkey, new List<int> { Index });
    }
    public List<int> FindIndices(string InputString, string Delimiter)
    {
        return FindIndices(InputString.Split(Delimiter.ToArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
    }
    //This return a list of indices that contain all the search words.  You will
    //probably need to work out how to implement partial results, but this
    //should give you a start
    public List<int> FindIndices(IEnumerable<string> InputArray)
    {
        //Get a list of indices for each word
        var templist = (from word in InputArray
                        where Collection.ContainsKey(word)
                        select Collection[word]);
        //Flatten the lists and remove duplicates and return every index that is
        //common to all the words.
        return (from index in templist.SelectMany(x => x).Distinct()
                where templist.All(x => x.Contains(index))
                select index).ToList();
    }

    public void Add(string key, List<int> value)
    {
        Collection.Add(key, value);
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(string key)
    {
        return Collection.ContainsKey(key);
    }

    public ICollection<string> Keys
    {
        get
        {
            return Collection.Keys;
        }
    }

    public bool Remove(string key)
    {
        return Collection.Remove(key);
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(string key, out List<int> value)
    {
        return Collection.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    }

    public ICollection<List<int>> Values
    {
        get
        {
            return Collection.Values;
        }
    }
    public void Clear()
    {
        Collection.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<string, List<int>> item)
    {
        return Collection.Contains(item);
    }


    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, List<int>>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Collection.GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Collection.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Add(KeyValuePair<string, List<int>> item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<string, List<int>>[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public bool Remove(KeyValuePair<string, List<int>> item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll try to study it a bit first since I'm quite new to making a new collection myself. Thanks

Comment: disclaimer : this answer possibly works too, but my accepted answer seems more understandable for a new dev like me. thanks.